# Using for loop in lapply

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply

Lets take a dataframe,

```
dataset = data.frame(env = c(1:3),
                rep = c(1:3),
                ind1 = c(1:5),
                ind2 = c(6:8),
                dep = rnorm(180, mean = 100, sd=10)
                )
```

The data is further divided to form a list as,

```
datsplit =  split(dataset, dataset$env)
```

I am trying to apply this loop over the list.

```
zz = function(x){
  twt <- tapply(x[, 5], x[, 3:4], mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  Means <- twt
  testers <- ncol(twt)
  lines <- nrow(twt)
  SCA <- twt
  for (i in 1:lines) {
    for (j in 1:testers) {
      SCA[i, j] <- twt[i, j] - mean(twt[, j]) - mean(twt[i, ]) + 
                           mean(twt)
    }
  }
}
```

The above function is looped over the list using `lapply`.

```
lapply(datsplit, zz)
```

But the result is showing NULL. (The result should have been in a matrix form)

```
$`1`
NULL

$`2`
NULL

$`3`
NULL
```

Here is an **Example** when applied to dataframe `dataset`.

```
twt <- tapply(dataset[, 5], dataset[, 3:4], mean, na.rm = TRUE)
Means <- twt
testers <- ncol(twt)
lines <- nrow(twt)
SCA <- twt
for (i in 1:lines) {
  for (j in 1:testers) {
    SCA[i, j] <- twt[i, j] - mean(twt[, j]) - mean(twt[i, ]) + 
      mean(twt)
  }
}
}

SCA
    ind2
ind1         6         7          8
   1 -3.053776  0.726515  2.3272607
   2 -2.717726  3.549950 -0.8322246
   3  1.014952  1.906804 -2.9217556
   4  3.572287 -4.175673  0.6033861
   5  1.184263 -2.007596  0.8233333
```

The expected output should be a list of 3 with 5x3 matrix.

Comment: FYI, it's bad practice to use `1:lines`, much better to use `seq_len(nrow(twt))`. Why? Because it works great when there are 1 or more rows, but in the event there is ever a 0-row frame (it happens!), then `1:nrow(twt)` resolves to `1:0` *which iterates twice*, and it will fail/error. The expectation of `1:nrow(twt)` when there are 0 rows is that it will return nothing and therefore do nothing in the `for` loop; `seq_len(nrow(twt))` does exactly what one expects and needs in those situations.

Comment: @r2evans I have tried replacing `lines` with `seq_len(nrow(twt))` but it returns a warning message `In 1:seq_len(nrow(twt)) :
  numerical expression has 5 elements: only the first used`.

Comment: Are you trying `for (i in seq_len(nrow(twt)))` or `for (i in 1:seq_len(nrow(twt)))`? The `seq_len(.)` returns a vector, never precede it with `1:`.

Comment: @r2evans Tried both. The former returns list of zeros whereas latter returns a warning message.

Comment: first you do not need a forloop. Just do `t(t(twt-rowMeans(twt)) - colMeans(twt)) + mean(twt)` or use `outer` ie `twt - outer(rowMeans(twt), colMeans(twt), '+') + mean(twt)`

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks, man. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `zz()` doesn't return anything. Try this:

```
zz = function(x){
  twt <- tapply(x[, 5], x[, 3:4], mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  Means <- twt
  testers <- ncol(twt)
  lines <- nrow(twt)
  SCA <- twt
  for (i in 1:lines) {
    for (j in 1:testers) {
      SCA[i, j] <- twt[i, j] - mean(twt[, j]) - mean(twt[i, ]) + 
        mean(twt)
    }
  }
  # Return the SCA object
  SCA
}

lapply(datsplit, zz)
#> $`1`
#>     ind2
#> ind1 6
#>    1 0
#>    2 0
#>    3 0
#>    4 0
#>    5 0
#> 
#> $`2`
#>     ind2
#> ind1 7
#>    1 0
#>    2 0
#>    3 0
#>    4 0
#>    5 0
#> 
#> $`3`
#>     ind2
#> ind1 8
#>    1 0
#>    2 0
#>    3 0
#>    4 0
#>    5 0
```

Comment: Result should be a list of 3 with 5x3 matrix.

Comment: In that case it seems you're not using `tapply()` correctly. I think to get a more helpful answer you'll need to add an expected output to your question. Some comments in the `zz()` function that indicate what each step is supposed to do would also be helpful!

Comment: @NadPat You are using tapply on dataset instead of `datsplit` and thats why you are claiming that you need a 5*3 matrix. Unless you change the values in `ind2` to something like `rep(6:8, length=180)` otherwise you will not get what you want